# Laravel Eloquent ignore protected $with

Tags: php, database, laravel, eloquent, builder

So Basically i have the model foo:

```php
protected $with = ['bars'];

public function bars()
{
   return $this->morphMany(bar::class, 'barable');
}
```

And the model bar:

```php
public function barable() 
{
   return $this->morphTo();
}
```

Now my question is, if i want to load foo via bar:

```php
Bar::find(1)->with(['barable.something.this'])->get();
```

I get the foo table alongside with the corresponding bar.

Now because the bars attribute of foo has many entries (including the original bar which i request the foo through) i want to exclude the barable.bars, but since its included in the with attribute, it's always loaded.

How can i exclude barable.bars from my query?

edit: I'm using laravel 5.6 if that matters

Comment: remove `protected $with = ['bars'];`

Comment: problem being, this is the only case in which i don't need bars, in every other query i need bars

Comment: ok, in this case, you can use `makeHidden` function

Comment: Tried it like this: `Bar::find(1)->makeHidden(['barable.bars'])->with(['barable.something.this'])->get();`
But im getting 
`Method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::makeHidden does not exist.` as an error

Answer (score 2):

Try using `$books = Book::without('author')->get();` like written in [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading-by-default).

So in your case it would be

`Bar::find(1)->with(['barable' => function ($query){ $query->without('bars'); $query->with(['something.this']) }])->get();`

Comment: How would i implement this if i want to use Books::find or Books::orderBy?

Comment: Can you try like this? `Books::find(1)->without('author')->get();` or `Books::without('author')->orderBy('id')->get();`

Comment: if i try it like `Books::find(1)->makeHidden(['barable.bars'])->with(['barable.something.this'])->get();` i get
`Method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::makeHidden does not exist` 
and using
`Books::makeHidden(['streamable.streams'])->orderBy('id')->with(['barable.something.this'])->get();`
I get:
`Non-static method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model::makeHidden() should not be called statically`

Comment: have you tried method `without` not `makeHidden` ?

Comment: if you mean `Books::find(1)->without(['barable.bars'])->with(['barable.something.this'])->get()`
it includes barable.bars

Comment: i don't know if this is important for that matter, but i don't use the latest version, i am using 5.6 (edited question to include it)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227959/discussion-between-scarvite-and-miqayel-srapionyan).